# How to rotate controllers in all selected keys by 90 degrees in world y axis at pivot [5,6,7]?

Tags: maya, mel

I have a animation which is okay from 1 to 50 keys. after 50th key I want the keys to be rotated by 180 degrees

I can use the below command to rotate 1 controller in 1 selected key

```
//mel
rotate -y 50 -ws -p 5 6 7;
```

but is very time consuming how can I do it for all selected controllers and keys ?

so it there a straight forward way to execute a mel command on keys. and how to proceed doing something like this?

Comment: Hello, could you tell us what have you tried so far? You're not new here, you might know that SO is not a code factory. Give us a bit of your researches even if they are inconclusive.

Comment: I am new to maya and mel, to execute the  command  i tried various ways to select the objects and keys but it dint seem to work, I looked online couldnt find anyway, i can select all objects using the mel and rotate  but that wouldnt rotate them at the keys, i wanted to know is there any simple selection process by which i can execute a rotate command on all selected key.

i only need to be pointed in the right direction, i can work out the code my self

Comment: I'd suggest you switch to Python before you get too deep into this -- the actual code won't be to hard but the Mel versions will always be wordier and more complex to maintain than the python equivalents.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this in python, since it's far easier to solve in Python than mel. It's pretty bare bones but it should be a good starting point:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds        # cmds is the python version of mel's api
obj = 'rig:rig:Root'            # your obj..  in real code you'd make a 
                                # function and ask for an object name
attributes = 'rx', 'ry', 'rz'   # need to ask where the keys for on each channel
rotation_keys = set()  # this avoids duplications of key times

# collect a list of all the frames which have any rotation key
for attrib in attributes:      
    for key in cmds.keyframe(obj, attribute = 'rx',  q=True, tc=True):
        rotation_keys.add(key)

# sort them by time, you now have a list of every rotate key time        
keyframe_list = sorted(rotation_keys)

for key in keyframe_list:
    if key > 50:
        # scrub to the right time
        cmds.currentTime(key)

        # apply the rotation relatively
        cmds.xform(obj, rotation = [0,180,0], ws =True, relative = True)

        # get the channel values and make sure they are all keyed
        for attrib in attributes:
            new_value = cmds.getAttr(obj + "." + attrib)
            cmds.setKeyframe(obj, attribute = attrib, time = key, value = new_value)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is to group your animated node, and set a key to rotate the group after frame 50.

If that's not an option, there is a common technique for putting the result of accumulated hierarchical animation onto a single node. It uses constraint nodes. You don't need to do any programming, but you can script the steps if you like.

1. Create a locator at the origin.
2. Select your node and shift select the locator.
3. Choose Constrain->Orient
4. Choose Constrain->Point (not necessary, but visually helpful)
5. Select the locator only.
6. Choose Edit->Keys->BakeSimulation [] (keys from channel-box, sample
   by 1,disable implicit control)
7. Hilight translate and rotate channels in the channel box and hit the
   Bake button.

The locator now moves and rotates with your node. The key values may be different if your node is in some hierarchy, but the motion should be coincident. Now you can modify the motion and transfer it back with the same process:

1. Group the locator, set the group pivot and and animate the group
   until the locator has the desired motion.
2. Delete the keys on your node.
3. Select the locator and shift select your node.
4. Choose Constrain->Orient, then choose Constrain->Point.

Now your node moves with the modified locator motion. At this stage, you can modify the locator animation further, tweak, add more group transforms and so on. Your node will update.

Finally, select your node and choose Keys->BakeSimulation with the same options as above, and delete the locator group.